# Alternative to the 'let' keyword in a loop?

Tags: javascript

I was having an issue where I was setting up a bunch of timeout calls and I wanted the timeout function to reference the element in the current loop.

This is what the result looked like:

```
    var createTimedMessages = function(arr, collection){
        var timeLimit = 2000;
        for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            let el = arr[i];
            collection.push(el);
            $timeout(function removeElement(){
                collection.removeMatch(el);
            }, timeLimit);
        }
    }
```

but I realized that this wouldn't work with some slightly older browsers because of lack of support for the let keyword. What is a good workaround?

Note: This is in angular, hence the $timeout rather than setTimeout.

Comment: Use a nested function/closure - it's been done (and worked like this) for years.

Comment: Yep, sorry, just realized that @user2864740 found the better dup target.

Comment: @Doorknob *But* that question has a better coverage of an IIFE. Putting the two together -> win.

Answer (score 4):

Use a IIFE:

```
var createTimedMessages = function(arr, collection) {
    var timeLimit = 2000;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        (function(el) {
            collection.push(el);
            $timeout(function removeElement() {
                collection.removeMatch(el);
            }, timeLimit);
        })(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Self-executing functions should solve the problem:

```
(function(el, timeLimit) {
    $timeout(/* your code */);
})(arr[i], timeLimit);
```